# Should Maven multiple module projects have a src directory in the parent?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

The [Maven Checkstyle Plugin - Multimodule Configuration Guide](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html) has a src directory in the parent project.

I have no idea what would go in here since I thought any src directories would go in the modules themselves.

So, should Maven multiple module projects have a src directory in the parent? And if so, what would go in there that wouldn't belong in a sub-module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is required in that directory.  Its just there to show that it follows the same convention. In the example, the directory is empty.

If you wanted to have Maven create a "site" for your application, "src/site" is where you would put your additional configuration information. You would then have a "parent" site created that points to all of the modules.